# On click select all row

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

Here the code which i have used for show the tick mark in table row,On each row click tick mark showing and on other click its hiding.I added a button to select make all ticks visible(Select all),it not working.

```
local function onRowRender( event )
 local phase = event.phase
 local row = event.row
 chktick= display.newImage('images/kitchen/checktick.png',10,10);
  if(deviceName == "iPhone" or deviceName == "iPad") then
   chktick.x=303;
  chktick.isVisible = false;
  else 
   chktick.x=303;   
  chktick.isVisible = false;
  end
 chktick.y=row.contentHeight * 0.5;
 row:insert(chktick);
 row:addEventListener("tap",onRowTouch); 
 return true;
end
```

On rowtouch method

```
local function onRowTouch( event )
local row = event.target;
local _chktick = event.target[6];
 print("Comes here when touch"..row.index);
  if(flagvalue==1)then
    _chktick.isVisible = true;
   flagvalue=0;
 else
    _chktick.isVisible = false;
  flagvalue=1;
 end
return true; 
end
```

Select all method

```
local function SelecetAllEventListener( event )
  flagvalue=1;
  currentScene.reloadScene();
 return true;
end
```

Rowrender calling code

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
MenuID = event.params.currentMenuID;
local group = self.view
    tableView = widget.newTableView
     {
      top = 85,
      left = 0,
      width = 320, 
      height = 380,
      maskFile = "billmask.png",
      hideBackground = true,
      onRowRender = onRowRender,
      listener = tableViewListener,
    }
   end
  group:insert( tableView )
end
```

Please help me how to make visible all tick showable in using **SelecetAllEventListener**?

Comment: Are you trying to have the button cause every row to be check marked? is the 6th item in your row group the check mark cell (I think you mean check mark not tick mark)? Where does onRowRender get called, can you show that code? And the button code too.

Comment: @Schollii Yes,On single button click every row to be checked marked.i have added the code please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that in your "select all" handler (`SelecetAllEventListener`) you are setting a flag to 1 then reloading the scene. This will cause, IIUC, the onRowRender to be called again, but it won't cause the onRowTouch to be called again (since there hasn't been a touch of a row). What you need to do is that in `SelecetAllEventListener` you loop over all your rows and change the visibility of the checkmark. Your code doesnt' show where you keep your rows but I will assume in a variable:

```
local tableRows = {}
local toggle = true

local function somewhereInYourCode()
    ...
    newRow = ...
    yourTable:inserRow(newRow) -- will cause onRowRender to get called
    table.insert(tableRows, newRow)
    ...
end

local function SelecetAllEventListener( event )
    for i,row in ipairs(tableRows) do
        row[6].isVisible = toggle
    end
    toggle = not toggle -- for next time
    return true
end
```

Your code doesn't show where you insert rows so I put it in `somewhereInYourCode()` but you get the idea.